# angular library, secondary entry points with shared resources?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library, ng-packagr

I'm trying to make an angular library with secondary entry points.

I have 2 entry points: `input` and `select`:

```
library
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┗ _all.scss
 ┣ select
 ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┣ components
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ error-list
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ error-list.component.html
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ error-list.component.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ error-list.component.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ select
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ select.component.html
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ select.component.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ select.component.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ models
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ select.model.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ select.module.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ public_api.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┗ value-accessor-base.ts
 ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┣ input
 ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┣ components
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ error-list
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ error-list.component.html
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ error-list.component.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ error-list.component.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ input
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ input.component.html
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ input.component.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ input.component.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ models
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ input.model.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ input.module.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ public_api.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┗ value-accessor-base.ts
 ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ public-api.ts
 ┃ ┗ test.ts
 ┣ .browserslistrc
 ┣ .eslintrc.json
 ┣ karma.conf.js
 ┣ ng-package.json
 ┣ package.json
 ┣ README.md
 ┣ tsconfig.lib.json
 ┣ tsconfig.lib.prod.json
 ┗ tsconfig.spec.json
```

As you can see here `error-list.component` is inside both entry points.

when I am trying to create a separate entry point `shared` for `error-list.component`, and then import `error-list.component` inside `input` and `select` from `shared` entry point, build fails with error: `Error: not in root dir`

How can I make this work, I mean how to have shared resources between secondary entry points? Or maybe there is some different workaround?

Comment: Seems like you have already posted this [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253731/how-to-have-shared-component-between-secondary-entry-points) today. It looks like the same general question.

Comment: Whad do you call an entry point?

Comment: Let's have a look at it together in a zoom call or so.

Comment: how is it suppose to work with 2 entry points? can you maybe elaborate on your original idea?

Comment: Does both `error-list.component.ts` have the same code inside them?